# Extra decimal places in a CSV File via shell script

Tags: bash, awk

I have several CSV files, where I want to fill the decimal places to 3 decimal places.
Example:

```
0.42 to 0.4200,
0.11 to 0.1100,
60112 to 60112.00


awk 'BEGIN { FS="," } { print($2)}' beta.csv
```

How do I attach extra decimal places?

[image]

Comment: `0.4200` has 4 decimal places , `60112.00` has 2 decimal places. So 4, 3 or 2? Please post some of example CSV file, like 2 or 3 lines. I would use `xargs` with `--delimter` to separate over comma and then format the output any how I want with just `printf`

Comment: Please add sample input (no images) and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Data:

```
$ cat foo
0.42 to 0.4200,
0.11 to 0.1100,
60112 to 60112.00
```

Awk:

```
$ awk '{print $1 ($1~/\./?"":".") "00" }' foo
0.4200
0.1100
60112.00
```

Ie. if there is a decimal point in the value, output `00` in the end. If not, output `.` first.